# Clipping due to segmentation in Plane primitive in away3d

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, away3d

I have a Plane and I try tweening a MovieClipSprite on it. I run into trouble when I try to tween near the points where both segment triangles meet (I have kept both segments as 1), While moving near these points the Sprite disappears.

I can tell it goes beneath the Plane because when it reappears it does so gradually and I can see it's lower half appearing as it moves away from these points.

Increasing the segments obviously deteriorates the performance further as this begins to happen at other points as well.

I am pasting some relevant code, if that may help

```
var planeMaterial:BitmapMaterial = new BitmapMaterial(texture.bitmapData, {smooth: true, precision: 4});
```

`plane = new Plane({material: planeMaterial,
                height: SIDE_LENGTH,
                width: SIDE_LENGTH,
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                z: 0,
                segmentsH: 1,
                segmentsW: 1,
                bothsides: false,
                yUp: true
            });`

```
        addChild(plane);
```

I tried clipping, Rectangle and Frustum but that doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a Z sorting problem to me. Try adjusting your code so that they are not at the same depth, ie move the plane further back.

Comment: Thank's davivid. It was a z-sorting problem, I just used **pushback** property of the **plane** to make sure it always renders before any of it's children